# I get this error "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict", how do i fix it?

Tags: python, arrays

I get this error when i run the script "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict", how do i fix it?

```
 CarNumbers = [
    {"number":"ABC 123", "oil":"10"},
    {"number":"ABC 124", "oil":"11"},
    {"number":"ABC 125", "oil":"12"}
]
IsValidCarNumber = False;

def check_database(msg):
    i = 0;
    for i in CarNumbers:
        print(msg);
        if CarNumbers[i][number] == msg:
            IsValidCarNumber = True;
        else:
            IsValidCarNumber = False;
```

Comment: Think of it - you're already extracting elements from `CarNumbers`. Why do you think you need to call it again within the `for` cycle? Just do `i["number"] == msg`. Also get rid of semicolons, you don't need them in Python.

Comment: There are multiple issues here. When you try to execute CarNumbers[i][number] i needs to be an int - which it isn't - it's a reference to one of the dictionaries in the CarNumbers list. If it was an int then CarNumbers[i]['number'] would work. Having said that, this is the least of your problems

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an expert with lists yet